# Multidimensional boolean indexing into multidimensional array

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, indexing, boolean

I am trying to use a multi-dimensional boolean index into a multi-dimensional array. Here is a simple version of what I am trying to do.

```
import numpy as np
pf=np.array([[[-67.  ,-20.35, 1],
              [-46.35, 33.25, 2],
              [  1   ,  2   , 1],
              [  4   ,  4   , 4]],
             [[-64.  ,-70.35, 8],
              [-46.35, 33.25, 7],
              [  3   ,  7   , 8],
              [  9   ,  3   , 2]]])
booly=np.array([[False, True, False, False],
                [False, False, False, True]])
```

I would like to use my boolean array to select the true values from my initial (2,4,3) array to obtain the final (2,3) array without a loop:

```
truth=np.array([[-46.35, 33.25, 2],
                [  9   ,  3   , 2]])
```

I have tried and failed. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

numpy supports [boolean indexing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html#boolean-or-mask-index-arrays):

```
res = pf[booly]
print(res)
# [[-46.35  33.25   2.  ]
# [  9.     3.     2.  ]]
```

Comment: I have tried that and I can't understand why that has not been working in my real life code, as far as i can tell it is the exact same except for the fact that the dimensions are much larger. I must have an error somewhere. Thanks though at least I know I am not crazy then